# SQL add values based on conditions then dived the two sums

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have one table called Data.

`Data
Year    Type    Value
1       1       5
1       1       10
1       2       15
1       2       25
1       1       15
1       2       20
1       1       5
2       2       10
2       2       45
2       2       10
2       1       20
2       2       5
2       1       15
2       1       0`

I would like per year sum everything that is type 1 (sum1) and sum everything that is type 2 (sum2) and then divide sum1 by sum2 and group the result by year. For year one that would be sum1=(5+10+15+5=35), sum2=(15+25+20=60), sum1(35)/sum(60)=0.58333. The complete output would be

`Year Value
1    0.5833
2    0.5`

I have tried the following query, but it doesn't work.
`SELECT d.Year, a.Sum1/b.Sum2
FROM Data d,
(SELECT Data.Year, SUM(Value) AS Sum1 FROM Data WHERE Type=1 GROUP BY Data.Year) a, 
(SELECT Data.Year, SUM(Value) AS Sum2 FROM Data WHERE Type=2 GROUP BY Data.Year) b
GROUP BY d.Year`

When I run the query I get `You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'a.Sum1/b.Sum2' as part of an aggregate function.` What is it I'm doing wrong in my query?

Comment: there is only type 1 and type 2. your query mentions type 4. it is a typo error?

Comment: Yes it is a typo I have updated the post now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use use IIF function

```
select Year,sum(iif(Type=1, value, 0))/sum(iif(Type=4, value, 0))
from data
GROUP BY Year
```